# POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/oauth/access_token. 400 Bad Request! "message":"Missing authorization code". Laravel socialite. laravel 7.5

Tags: php, laravel

i'm using laravel socialite and i setup the .env as these parameters:

```
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=""
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=""
FACEBOOK_AOUTH_REDIRECT_URL="https://example.com/public/login/facebook/callback"
```

But all requests to login by facebook get this result:

```
Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":{"message":"Missing authorization code","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"AVOEL7CdobAM6pi_jBB2h-1" (truncated...)
```

So what the solution ? help me please !

Comment: Make sure the client secret is accessible on the return URL controller.

Comment: Did you leave FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID and FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET configs empty? If so you have to provide them

Comment: no i didn't ! the client_id & client_secret are true and match the given data from facebook.